# Device Management application in Android 2.2

Tags: android, mdm, device-policy-manager

This is regarding google apps Device Management policy third party application which I got from android market in 2.2 .

I registered an account in Google Apps domain in order to use this account for enabling  device management policies. I need to know the process in which remote wipe out feature can be achieved using this application in an enterprise manner. I need to login as an administrator in this application and need to wipe out the user secured data in his device on his request.

Is there a way in which I can achieve this using this 3rd party application?

I will be waiting for reply  with the process in which this application can be used in Enterprise scenario.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for device management in an enterprise scenario, you might want to take a look at Oracle Database Lite Mobile Server.

It provides enterprise device management features, including the ability to remotely wipe data on the client. However it does much more than that. It also includes a configurable two-way data sync engine and a management console for provisioning and monitoring devices. You can read more about it, and even try it out here:

http://bit.ly/eJOzhN

Maybe overkill for what you’re trying to do, but if you also need to provision applications and sync data between your devices and a backend database, this could be an ideal solution for you.
Good luck, hope you find a solution that meets your needs.

-- Eric

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not programming related.

Please use:
https://android.stackexchange.com/
for Android superuser type questions.